# Adblock Plus disable on sites with specific class

Tags: ads, adblock

Does abp offer any way to be disabled on sites where a specific class or term is found? I'm trying to disable it on sites that I frequently have to work with ads on.

I have looked on the filter docs and it seems that you can only enable filters to enable ad block where specific elements are found, not disable where a specific class/term is found.

Any help would be great, thanks!